# How to add value="" to input

Tags: javascript

Is there a possibility to add the value tag to an input with javascript?

e.g. to change a input fild in a form from:

```
<input type="text" name="mail" id="mail">
```

to:

```
<input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email'] ?>
```

EDIT:

```
<?php
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("mail").setAttribute("value", "<?php echo $_SESSION["email"];?>");

</script>';
?>
```

Comment: Javascript can't get a PHP session variable by itself.

Comment: It´s not about handling the session variable its more add the whole string "value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']" to the input field

Comment: Do you want to change the current value of the input or its initial default?

Comment: `element.setAttribute("value", "foo@bar.com")`

Comment: If you put `<?php echo ...?>` you'll see that literal string, is that really what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setAttribute()` to fill in the attribute of an element.

```js
document.getElementById("mail").setAttribute("value", "<?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?>");
```

```html
<input type="text" name="mail" id="mail">
```

You can't use `<?php` inside a PHP string. Use concatenation instead.

```
<?php
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("mail").setAttribute("value", "' . $_SESSION["email"] . '");

</script>';
?>
```

Comment: If I run this the field gets filled with the email adress. Any idea how I can echo this from php? echo'
<script type="text/javascript">

document... does not work

Comment: Just use `?>` to get out of PHP execution mode, so it just outputs the HTML and Javascript literally, slipping back into PHP mode for the `echo` statement.

Comment: sorry I didn´t get you last post. I updated my initial question. Any idea what is the error?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome, it worked! thanks a lot! (its already late in good old germany ;))

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can access the value field of an input with javascript

```
document.getElementById('mail').value = "someemail@email.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but you could save PHP value as a JS variable and go from there. Something like this?

```
var email = '<?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?>';
document.getElementById('mail').value = email;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the method **echo**, returning the element input.

```
$youvalue = "This is the value of the input"
echo '<input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" value="'.$yourvalue.'">';
```

Using the method **echo** again, returning a script.

```
$youvalue = "This is the value of the input"
echo '<script>var x = document.createElement("input");x.type = "text";x.name = "mail";x.id = "mail";x.value = "'.$youvalue.'"; document.body.appendChild(x);</script>'
```